# Organize ember templates in folders

Tags: ember.js

I have a router map like this:

```
this.resource('eng', function(){
    this.route('home');
    this.resource('eng.rent', {path: 'rent' }, function(){
        this.route('boulderSmall', {path: 'boulder-small'});
        this.route('boulderXl', {path: 'boulder-xl'});
    });     
});
```

the template files are stored in "templates/eng" folder; for the "home" and "eng.rent" routes everything is ok: Ember can find by itself where the template files are; but for the other routes i have to specify where the template is, like:

```
Importclimbing.EngRentBoulderSmallRoute = Importclimbing.StdEngRoute.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('eng/boulderSmall');
    }
});
```

Can someone explain how Ember looks for template files? For example, if i don't specify "renderTemplate" for EngRentBoulderSmallRoute as above, the template will not render (even if i put the "boulderSmall.hbs" file into "template" folder instead of "template/eng"; and so, where Ember look for this template by default? And if i would like to store "boulderSmall.hbs" into "templates/eng/rent" folder,  which path should i pass to renderTemplate function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got rid of this;
the kiwiupower's answer was correct, since Ember looks for template files in folders and subfolders as indicated;
the problem was due to yeoman, that i use for development; in the gruntfile, the default setup  looks for Ember templates only through one level of folders;

to make yeoman able to look also deeper in templates folder structure, i made this changes:

1 to the watch task for livereload:

```
 emberTemplates: {
            files: '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/**/**/*.hbs',
            tasks: ['emberTemplates', 'livereload']
        },
```

I've added a "**/" in order to let the task watch also the second level of subfolders in templates directory

2 in Ember templates task:

```
 emberTemplates: {
        options: {
            templateName: function (sourceFile) {
                var templatePath = yeomanConfig.app + '/templates/';
                return sourceFile.replace(templatePath, '');
            }
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                '.tmp/scripts/compiled-templates.js': '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/{,*/}{,*/}*.hbs'
            }
        }
    }
```

I've added a "{,*/}" into the dist.files object;
If you need yeoman to watch for/ compile third level of subfolders or more, you need to modify this two tasks adding more "**/" and "{,*/}"

Answer (score 5):

Your folder structure should look like this.

First you need to rename the `eng.rent` route `rent` so the router looks like this

```
this.resource('eng', function(){
    this.route('home');
    this.resource('rent', {path: 'rent' }, function(){
        this.route('boulderSmall', {path: 'boulder-small'});
        this.route('boulderXl', {path: 'boulder-xl'});
    });     
});
```

Then your templates and folders should be named this way.

```
templates          ## this is a folder
  |--eng           ## this is a folder
      |--home.hbs
  |--rent      ## this is a folder
      |--boulder_small.hbs
      |--boulder_xl.hbs
  application.hbs
  eng.hbs
  rent.hbs
```

I hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Unfortunally it doesn't work; if i rename "reng.hbs" to "eng.rent.hbs" and put it into "templates" folder, it doesn't render (it's ok keeping it into templates/eng folder and naming it simply "rent.hbs");  and it's the same with subroutes, if i put the hbs files into eng.rent subfolder, they don't render...

Comment: No, still not working; this is one of the first tries i've made (except that i've named all the .hbs files in camelcase, like boulderSmall.hbs); I use yeoman to deploy the ember app, i don't know if this changes something...

Comment: Another thing: i should not change the route names (from eng.rent to rent, since i have other languages'routes with same name (ex. ita.rent))... Thanks for help